# How can I convert split function to inline table valued udf in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, inline-table-function

Assuming I have this query  ( pseudo) :

```
Select T.a,
       T.b, 
       (select top 1 element from fn_split(c,',') where element=T.element)
From largeTable T
```

Where `fn_split` runs for each row , I would like to use  inline table valued udf  so , that performance will be better.

NB : `fn_split` just create a table via splitting via `,` :

[image]

But looking at inline table valued udf *structure*  :

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_...]
(
    ...
)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN  SELECT ...(!!!)
```

It should return the select right away  as the first statement !

But what if my UDF looks like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Split] 
(
    @InDelimitedString varchar(max),
    @InDelimiter       varchar(10) 
)
RETURNS 
    @tblArray TABLE 
    (
        ElementID  smallint IDENTITY(1,1), 
        Element    varchar(1000)
    )

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StrPos smallint,
    @StrStart smallint,
    @DelimiterLength smallint

    SET @DelimiterLength = LEN(@InDelimiter)    

    WHILE LEN(@InDelimitedString) > 0
        BEGIN
         --Removed for clarity . do some CHARINDEX  manipulation ETc.
        END

    RETURN 
END
```

**Question :**

I can't return `select` right away , but still , I want to change the `fn_split` to inline table valued udf.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your split function. It is doing the split in an [**RBAR**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) fashion. You should use a set-based splitter. Here is the [**DelimitedSplit8k**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden, which is one of the fastest splitter there is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](
    @pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,cteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString), 0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)
,cteStart(N1) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
),
cteLen(N1, L1) AS(
SELECT 
    s.N1,
    ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1),0) - s.N1, 8000)
FROM cteStart s
)
SELECT 
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
```

*Note: Be sure to look into the article for the updated function*

---

For more split functions, read these articles by Sir Aaron Bertrand:

- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)
- [Comparing string splitting / concatenation methods](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat)
- [Processing a list of integers : my approach](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/01/processing-a-list-of-integers-my-approach)
- [Splitting a list of integers : another roundup](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup)
- [More on splitting lists : custom delimiters, preventing duplicates, and maintaining order](https://sqlblog.org/2009/08/06/more-on-splitting-lists-custom-delimiters-preventing-duplicates-and-maintaining-order)
- [Removing Duplicates from Strings in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4140/removing-duplicates-from-strings-in-sql-server/)

Comment: is this _inline table valued udf_ ??

Comment: God I love those  CTE's