# Best way to insert all combinations of input items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
firstname    lastname      address      city
    a          b           (c,d,e)      (f,g,h)
```

I want to make a series of inserts like this:

```
insert (a,b,c,f)
insert (a,b,c,g)
insert (a,b,c,h)
insert (a,b,d,f)
insert (a,b,d,g)
insert (a,b,e,h)
....
```

What is the best way to do that in SQL Server without using multiple cursors?

Comment: That table and those insert clauses don't really match -- and there is no cursor anywhere

Comment: Your question is not very clear. what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i should split address  and city by a comma and make an insert of all combinations

Comment: Storing multiple different data on the same row is usually not a good idea. Better  would be to have a separate address table that would have one address per row and it would have person_id or something like that to link to the names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create temp tables and generate an `insert into ... select` from a cartesian join:

```
create table #address(address varchar(1) not null)

insert into #address
values ('c'), ('d'), ('e')

create table #city(city varchar(1) not null)

insert into #city
values ('f'), ('g'), ('h')

insert into my_table
select 'a', 'b', address, city
from #address, #city
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82b9a/2

Comment: do this insert statement will insert all combinations of 
a,b with (c,d,e)  and (f,g,h)??

Comment: I'll try Monday at work and I'll let you know 
thanks :)

Comment: It will work for this example, but I doubt it will work for if some firstName/lastName combination doesn't have all of /f/g/h addresses or cities in your actual database. Solution provided by Zohan will always do the right job.

Comment: I was answering the question that was raised, not a theoretical different question. Believe me, I [don't mess with the Zohan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Don't_Mess_with_the_Zohan).

Comment: @ZoharPeled My apologies!

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas don't feel to bad about it, you are not the first nor the last :-)

Answer (score 6):

Simply use [`cross apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) with your table and some string splitting `udf`.
You can find the best one for you in [this article.](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

I've used for this demonstration the `SplitStrings_Moden` function from the article I've linked to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Moden
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

Once you have the splitting function, all you have to do is select the values from your table and use cross apply with this function for each comma delimited column you have:

```
-- INSERT INTO MyTable(firstname, lastname, address, city)
SELECT firstname, lastname, a.item, b.item
FROM MyTable
cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_Moden([address], ',') a
cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(city, ',') b
```

[See fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b38b/1)

Comment: Which udf is newer/better yours or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29961649/859154) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think they are almost the same (note that the split function in my answer is called `SplitStrings_Moden`, the same guy that wrote the split function in wewesthemenace's answer). Read the article I've linked to (or just look at the graphs and go to the Conclusion paragraph, apparently, Adam Machanic's CLR function gives the best performance in almost every case.

Comment: Except "the same guy" doesn't really like it when his code is changed to the point that it starts performing poorly while people still call it "a Moden function". Have you read the comments under the SQLPerformance article you've linked in your answer, Jeff Moden's comments in particular? Apparently his original function isn't really supposed to work with `max` types.

Comment: Other than that, the idea of using a split function makes perfect sense if the input is indeed provided in the form of CSV strings.

Comment: @AndriyM The exact splitting function is not the main issue in my answer. the main issue is that using a splitting function with cross apply gives a dynamic, pure t-sql solution to the OP's question. I admit I didn't read the comments to the article, but since the splitting function is not the main issue here, I don't think it's that relevant to this answer. If it will make you, Jeff, or anyone happy, I will happily edit my answer to change the split function to a different one.

Comment: For my part, it was no more than a heads-up that the function's author may not like it, given the extended discussion under the article. I agree, though, that the main point here is to use a split function and you've provided a source with a selection of them all right.

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for pointing that out - I didn't notice it. BTW , do you know a split UDF ( which does work with `max`) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The [article we've been discussing](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) offers (and actually tests) several methods implemented as functions with a `max` argument.

Comment: @RoyiNamir wasn't that what you are asking for? do you need a split function that does work with `max` or one that doesn't?